# Sort an array list of hashmaps by the value(comparing by value of map) of the hashmaps

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap, comparator

My list looks something like this

```java
List<Map<CustomClass,Integer>> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here each custom class is associated with a value where the class is taken as key and the value associated to it is the value for the map. I can have more than one 1 key to have same value.

For example:

```java
List<Map<CustomClass,Integer>> sampleList = new ArrayList<>();


CustomClass a1 = new CustomClass();
CustomClass a2 = new CustomClass();

CustomClass b1 = new CustomClass();
CustomClass b2 = new CustomClass();

Map<CustomClass, Integer> map1 = new HashMap();
map1.put(a1,3);
map1.put(a2,3);

Map<CustomClass, Integer> map2 = new HashMap();
map2.put(b1,2);
map2.put(b2,2);

sampleList.add(map1);
sampleList.add(map2);
```

Now I want the final sorted list to be having `{b1,b2,a1,a2}` i.e sorted based on integer value.

Comment: What are you sorting? The list or the map? The traditional way to implement a scenario where a key can have multiple values is to use a map of lists, not a list of maps...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen good question. At first glance, I thought the list had four maps with one key-value entry each. But then I saw the list has one single map and that one has four key-values. If it's *the map* that should be sorted, then it needs to be something different than HashMap, as those don't have an order. If it's *the list* that needs to be sorted, what exactly is the criteria, if you have multiple maps with multiple entries in each?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think you're right. Looks like that's what the op is after.

Comment: "*The traditional way to implement a scenario where a key can have multiple values is to use a map of lists*" and just a brief note on this a [multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) formalises this scenario.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Edited my post. I have to sort the list and not the map based on the ascending order of the numbers

Comment: @VLAZ : Thanks for suggesting multimaps. i ll try them

Comment: @gayu312 would the map always have the same value for the keys? Or is it possible to have `map1.set(a1, 1); map1.set(a2, 4);` and then `map2.set(b1, 2); map2.set(b2, 3);`? If that is possible, then how do you sort? By min value? By max value? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams to flatten the maps and sort by value:

```
List<CustomClass> result = sampleList.stream()
        .map(Map::entrySet)
        .flatMap(Set::stream)
        .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But I am trying to sort the list here and not the map but the list has to be sorted based on map's value.

Comment: This is sorted on the values.